# Can't set callback listener. In constructor value is ok, but inside method is always null

Tags: android, interface, constructor, callback, listener

I can't figure out where am I wrong. I have set up a listener for one of my classes (class A) where I save some user informations.

Back in main activity (class B) I have implemented the first class and I initialise the listener. Then in class B I create a constructor for the interface to finish initialisation here the value of the listener is somewhat ok: "value of the listeners on initialisation: com.fideli.MainActivity@425b0500", but bellow in the method I would like to use it I get always null, and my app crashes.

Where am I wrong? THANKS!!

Class A:

```
public class GCMActivity {

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    Context context; 


    public void setCallback(regidListener rListener) {
        this.rListener = rListener;     
        //here it is ok, it is not null
        System.out.println("value of the listeneris on initialisation: " + rListener);
    }

    public static interface regidListener {
        public void onRegIdSaved(String regId);
    }

    public regidListener rListener; 

    public GCMActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void registerIfNeeded() {
        // here is already null
        System.out.println("value of the listeneris: " + this.rListener);
        if (rListener != null){
        rListener.onRegIdSaved("HEY!!");    
        }

        if (checkPlayServices()) {           
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);
            System.out.println("Class Started!!");
            if (regid == null) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
```

Main activity, class B:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GCMActivity.regidListener  {


...

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();            
        if(!isOnline()){
            showGpsButton();            
         }      

        //initialising listener for regId ready
        GCMActivity gcm = new GCMActivity(this);
        gcm.setCallback(this);

    }


@Override
    public void onRegIdSaved(String regId) {
        System.out.println("regId ready" + regId);

    }

....
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because in your onResume method gcm is a local variable that goes out of scope when onResume returns? Seems like you need to make it a class variable, e.g. mGcm.

Comment: Maybe, after some experimenting I have removed the setCallback () method, and moved the initialisation into the default constructor, and it worked! But I would like to use the setCallback methot, and most to understand this behaviour.